# Apparent weight can be negative?

Tags: weight

Apparent weight can be negative ??  If yes then what conditions are required for this ? If we change the frame of reference is there any change occur in apparent weight due to these changes ?

Comment: Maybe apparent weight can be negative if you are in an elevator which is accelerating upwards at 2g.

Comment: If we change the frame of reference and reduced the downward force to almost zero and increases upward force than apparent weight b negative ??

Comment: what do you mean by downward force and upward force in this context?

Comment: Weight is always a downward force as it always due to gravity.. But if the upthurst of it is greater than its weight then what will b happened ?

Comment: this is exactly what I said in my first comment. You will feel an upward force equal to g but if you stand on a scale the scale will register as 2g( suppose your weight is 20 KG then the weighing scale on the elevator going upward with 2g acceleration will register as 40 KG)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74939/discussion-between-fatima-and-physics2000).

Answer (score 1):

When an object moves downwards with an acceleration greater than (g) that is $|\vec a | \gt | \vec g |$